# Limits outside of functions. Limits out of context.

Tags: limits

In the set of real numbers, if I want to write the number the comes after a particular number $a \in \mathbb{R}$, can I use the following notation?

$$\text{After } a \text{ follows: } a + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} h, \quad\text{where } h > 0$$

What is the correct way to write something like that?

Comment: With real numbers and their natural ordering, there is no number which immediately follows another number: there are more numbers between any two distinct numbers, including their average.  Your limit is $a$.